# Find a word using AWK

Tags: awk, text-processing

Is there a way to find a specific record among the whole line?

This is my file:

```
one two three four
two three four five
three four five six
four five six seven
five six seven eight
```

How do I search for all lines which include two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '/(^| )two( |$)/' ...
```

The `(..)` groups there are trying to ensure we're only matching "two". At the front it either needs to be the beginning of the line or a space and at the end it needs to be a space or the end of the line. In short, we're making sure the field equals two.

Hmm apparently you can also [use word-boundary tags](https://superuser.com/a/349119) (which looks slightly more elegant but isn't as portable):

```
awk '/\<two\>' ...
```

Not sure what your specific use-case is (I assume it's not numbers), you might be just as well off with `grep -E '\<two\>' ...` but `awk` will give you a bit more flexibility if you need to do other stuff.

Comment: thanks, for the second part, ( |$) I understand the usage of space. But for $ part , would you please add why $ stand for in here? {I just know $x refers to column x.

Comment: Simply: the end of the line. ^ means the start.

Answer (score 2):

For this simple task you can also use [grep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep.1.html):

```
grep  'two' /path/to/file
```

output:

```
one two three four
two three four five
```

To get the "two" if it is not at the beginning of a line:

`grep  ' two ' /path/to/file` ->`one two three four`

or with meta-characters to get it only at the beginning of a line:

`grep  '^two' /path/to/file` ->`two three four five`